# Datepicker with class selector - range functionality should only work inside the unit

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have repetitive html units as bellow,

html unit:

```
<div class="unit">      
    <div class="half">
        <label class="label-1">From : </label>
        <div class="input-container" >
            <input class="period-start" name="period[start][]" value="" type="text" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="half">
        <label class="label-1">Till : </label>
        <div class="input-container" >
            <input class="period-end" name="period[end][]" value="" type="text" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I initialize the `datepicker` with `period-start` and `period-end` classes. But this units are working as units. So I use `minDate` and `maxDate` to control the range. However it will effect all the units when I use following code.

jquery code:

```
    $( ".period-start" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( ".period-end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

    $( ".period-end" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( ".period-start" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
```

What I need is, date selection would effect only to the sibling `datepicker` inside the same unit.

Any help would appreciate.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in the `onClose` callbacks you are selecting `.period-start`, which selects all elements with that class on the page. What you want to do is only search for the one within the same unit. Something like this:

```
// onClose callback for period start
onClose: function(selectedDate) {
  $(this)
    .closest('.unit')
    .find('.period-end')
    .datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}

// onClose callback for period end
onClose: function(selectedDate) {
  $(this)
    .closest('.unit')
    .find('.period-start')
    .datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
}
```

With [`closest('.unit')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) you travel up in the dom to the nearest element with the class `unit`, then [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) an element with the class `.period-end` within that element (`.unit`).